# Run a script on my remote machine from my machine even when the connection is lost

Tags: ssh, remote-access

I have a remote machine where i need to run some script say `./main.sh`

I am using ssh to login to the remote machine and run the script but when the network connection is lost the script doesn't run.

How can i run a script on my remote machine from my machine even when the connection is lost? Are there any alternatives to ssh in this use case?

Comment: "rdesktop " has solved it.

  Steps are :
  -> Install "rdesktop " on your machine.

  -> Connect to remote host 
      rdesktop RemoteMachineAddress

  -> Run the script

  -> Close the rdesktop connection

Answer (score 1):

If the remote system is Unix-compatible, the standard answer is to use `nohup`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to `cron` on that machine, use that (see `man cron`) for regular runs.

If it's a single case scenario, and you want it to run sometimes after logging in (even if the connection is lost): after logging in, start a `screen` session and use `at`.